# Некоректное выполнение кода на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Компилятор кода выдаёт некорректный результат при определённых условиях:

По условию задачи я должен последовательно, в алфавитном порядке убирать буквы из слова/словосочетания. Код отлично работает, пока  в нём не появляются 2 одинаковые буквы (не символа).

Поясню на примере: из фразы "ещё не пример" в ходе цикла постепенно удаляются буквы, в одном из шагов получая следующий список: `['щ', ' ', 'н', ' ', 'п', 'р', 'р']`, а после этого, вместо того, чтобы удалить обе буквы "р", он удаляет лишь одну, тиражируя вторую до конца цикла.

```
inp = input()
inp_1 = []
for i in inp:
    inp_1.append(i)
dl = []
for i in inp_1:
    if i == ' ':
        dl.append(i)
s = ' ' * len(dl)
s_1 = []
for i in s:
    s_1.append(i)
alph = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'
for i in alph:
    for j in inp_1:
        if j == i:
            inp_1.remove(j)
        if len(s_1) != len(inp_1):
            print(*inp_1)
```

Для меня такое поведение довольно загадочно. Буду крайне благодарен за совет и помощь.

Comment: это для всех очень загадочно, пока ты не назвал переменные подходяще  и не убрал отступ перед каждой строкой.

Comment: Я не знаю, как он вообще что-либо выдаёт. Что за s_1, встречающаяся в коде лишь с атрибутом append, но так и не названная?

Comment: А что, цикл ` for j in inp_1:` обязан нормально работать, даже если внутри него `inp_1` почикали?

Comment: Вы удаляете элемента из списка, по которому итерируетесь. Не надо так делать. Это равносильно тому, что поменять колёса во время езды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем-то вам все сказали, но я не удержался помочь вам. Хотя больше пользы было бы если бы вы поняли самостоятельно.
Начнем сначала. Первые строчки работают верно, но их можно упростить:

```
inp = input()
inp_1 = []
for i in inp:
    inp_1.append(i)
```

это то же самое, что:

```
inp = input()
inp_1 = list(inp)
```

то же самое, но короче и быстрее. Далее не очень понятно что к чему, но если все переменные вам пригодяся в дальнейшем, то этот участок:

```
dl = []
for i in inp_1:
    if i == ' ':
        dl.append(i)
s = ' ' * len(dl)
s_1 = []
for i in s:
    s_1.append(i)
```

можно переписать как:

```
dl = inp_1.count(" ")*[" "]
s = inp_1.count(" ")*" "
s_1 = dl.copy()
```

вы уже знаете, что цикл надо делать по копии исходного текста.
итак - окончательный вариант:

```
inp = input()
inp_1 = list(inp)
dl = inp_1.count(" ")*[" "]
s = inp_1.count(" ")*" "
s_1 = dl.copy()

alph = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'

inp_1_copy = inp_1.copy()
for i in alph:
    for j in inp_1_copy:
        if j == i:
            inp_1.remove(j)
            if len(s_1) != len(inp_1):
                print(*inp_1)
```

хотя возможно, все еще проще и если вам в будущем не нужны  `dl` и `s`, то
вместо блока

```
dl = inp_1.count(" ")*[" "]
s = inp_1.count(" ")*" "
s_1 = dl.copy()
```

тоже достаточно одной строчки:

```
s_1 = inp_1.count(" ")*[" "]
```

Ваша основная ваша ошибка была в том, что вы удаляли данные из списка в цикле, организованном по этому списку. так нельзя.
Остальные предлрженные изменения  -  попытка упростить код.
Итак - итоговый вариант, если не нужны  `dl` и `s`:

```
inp_1 = list(input().lower())  #на всякий случай результат ввода переведен в нижний регистр
blank_num = inp_1.count(" ")    # подсчет количества пробелов

alph = 'абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя'

inp_1_copy = inp_1.copy()
for letter in alph:
    for char in inp_1_copy:
        if char == letter:
            inp_1.remove(letter)
            if blank_num != len(inp_1):   # печатаем только после удаления символа
                print(*inp_1)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!
Этих функций, предложенных вами для упрощения, не знал, поэтому делал как умел.
Единственное, печать после удаления символа для моей задачи лишнее. Там необходим как раз вывод inp_1 согласно количеству символов алфавита. Но с этим я разобрался.