# Python цикл пропускает элемент списка

Tags: python

```
f = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for x in f:
    print(x)
    if x == 3:
        f.append(9)
    if x == 1:
        f.remove(x)

print(f)
```

почему цикл пропускает значение 2

вывод:

```
1
3
4
5
9
[2, 3, 4, 5, 9]
```

Comment: потому что вы изменяете список, по которому идет цикл

Comment: @splash58

'f = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
`a = f

for x in f:
    print(x)
    if x == 3:
        a.append(9)
    if x == 1:
        a.remove(x)

print(a)`
вот я изменяю другой список аналогичный первому но тоже пропускается элемент

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с удалением элемента списка методом remove(), в цикле python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1032299/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-remove-%d0%b2-%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b5-python)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Некоректное выполнение кода на Python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1056159/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python)

Answer (score 3):

Это происходит потому что исходный список изменяется. Простой метод решения - это скопировать список.

```
f = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
f2 = f[:]

for x in f:
    if x == 3:
        f2.append(9)

    if x == 1:
        f2.remove(x)

print(f2)
```